# Scrolling LI's do not hide after appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of LIs that are fed upwards via javascript/jquery into view.  It works fine however, when it appends the first li to the end it keeps it visible.  I tried removing the slideDown() from my javascript but then it doesn't ever show and after the scrolls through the 10 items (there could be more or less) it stops.  I have CSS showing only the first five LI's in the which starts out fine.

How can I get the LI's to scroll up, remove the first one and append it hidden to the bottom so I get a continuous rotation of LI elements?  It's going to be a scrolling news feed once I get it working.

```
<style>
#news {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
    pading:0px;
    list-style:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#news .item {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
#news .item h2 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    border-color: inherit;
}
#news .item h2:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}
#news .item h2,
#news .item div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
}
.style1  { border-color: #697791 }
.style1 h2 { background: #697791 }
.style2  { border-color: #74936a }
.style2 h2 { background: #74936a }
.style3  { border-color: #dbbb06 }
.style3 h2 { background: #dbbb06 }
.style4  { border-color: #9C2528 }
.style4 h2 { background: #9C2528 }


#news li:nth-child(n+6) {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var seconds = 2    * 1000;

    function tick2(){
        $('#news li:first').slideUp("slow", function () { $(this).appendTo($('#news')).slideDown("slow"); });
    }
    var timer = setInterval(function(){ tick2 () }, seconds);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#news').hover(function(ev){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }, function(ev){
            timer = setInterval( function(){ tick2() } , seconds);
        });
    });

    </script>

<ul id="news">
   <li><div class="item style1">
        <h2>1</h2>
        <div>
            <p>fdsasdf asdif ksd jfkasjdfasj dfla sjdflj asdfljas dflkjsdf alskdjf asdfl fdsasdf asdif ksd jfkasjdfasj dfla sjdflj asdfljas dflkjsdf alskdjf asdfl fdsasdf asdif ksd jfkasjdfasj dfla sjdflj asdfljas dflkjsdf alskdjf asdfl fdsasdf asdif ksd jfkasjdfasj dfla sjdflj asdfljas dflkjsdf alskdjf asdfl fdsasdf asdif ksd jfkasjdfasj dfla sjdflj asdfljas dflkjsdf alskdjf asdfl</p>
        </div>
</div></li>
    <li><div class="item style2">
        <h2>2</h2>
        <div>
            <p>fareveae vasev</p>
        </div>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="item style2">
        <h2>3</h2>
        <div>
            <p>fareveae vasev</p>
        </div>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="item style2">
        <h2>4</h2>
        <div>
            <p>fareveae vasev</p>
        </div>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="item style2">
        <h2>5</h2>
        <div>
            <p>fareveae vasev</p>
        </div>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="item style2">
        <h2>6</h2>
        <div>
            <p>fareveae vasev</p>
        </div>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="item style3">
        <h2>7</h2>
        <div>
            <p>fareveae vasev</p>
        </div>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="item style2">
        <h2>8</h2>
        <div>
            <p>fareveae vasev</p>
        </div>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="item style4">
        <h2>9</h2>
        <div>
            <p>I'd love them to!!!</p>
        </div>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="item style3">
        <h2>10</h2>
        <div>
            <p>I love &hearts; testing!!!</p>
        </div>
    </div></li>


</ul>
```

Edit:  I've created a fiddle to show what's going on at https://jsfiddle.net/0bfuqq7z/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `appendTo` function to add an item inside the `<ul>` element or use the `after` function to add an element after the last `<li>` item, as I show here.  I basically added a blank list item to the end, hid it, then copied the first element to the hidden last element, then performed the slide animation on both, then removed the first item to complete the sequence.

```
function tick2(){
    $('#news li:last').after("<li>&nbsp;</li>");
    $('#news li:last').hide();
    $('#news li:last').html($('#news li:first').html());
    $('#news li:first').slideUp("slow", function(){
        $('#news li:first').remove();
    });
    $('#news li:last').slideDown("slow");        
}
```

Comment: I do use the appendTo function.  Your function causes the same problems as mine unfortunately. Example of what's going on here:  https://jsfiddle.net/0bfuqq7z/

Comment: Interesting.  I tested the function with a click event to cause the animation and it worked perfectly, so something else must be going on here.

Comment: If you remove the css `#news li:nth-child(n+6) { display: none; }` and give the #news div a fixed height, the scrolling works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/9jk0c0sr/